# How to import Adblock Plus pattern.ini into version 3.10.2

Tags: firefox, adblock

I have a pattern.ini from an old Adblock Plus installation version 2.8.2.

As far as I understand, it saved it custom filter rules under `adblockplus/pattern.ini`

I know have upgraded browser, and with it ABP to version 3.10.2. I can't find an option to import a filter list from a local file. There's "Add filter list via URL", but that accepts HTTPS URLs only. Is there a way to still import a local filter list, and if so, what is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can just do the following:

1. `grep -A 1 ^text= patterns.ini | grep 'text=|disabled=' > patterns.tmp`
2. edit patterns.tmp to remove all disable rules
3. `cut -c 6- patterns.tmp`
4. copy the output into the clipboard
5. in the add-on prefs, under "Advanced", focus the text box under "MY FILTER LIST", and paste the clipboard

It appears the plugin accepts new-line separated lines from the clipboard in that text box.

Yay.

Comment: This answer assumes linux OS or MinGW/Cygwin availability

Comment: Yes, it does. No idea how to do this on Windows.